# Properness of the moment map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$ which is algebraically completely integrable Hamiltonian system. Them $M$ admits $n$ independent functions $f_1, f_2, ...f_n$ which are in involution. These functions then induce a map $M \to \mathbb{C}^n$, which is known as the moment map.

Question: Is the moment map proper ?

Comment: If it is (by chance), just remove a closed subset of $M$ and you get a non proper moment map.

Comment: Can we say something for particular kind of algebraically completely integrable sysytem ? For example in the case when $M$ is the cotangent bundle of a manifold of dimension $n$ ?

Comment: No, I don't think so — usually you need to find some partial compactification of $T^*M$. This is the case for instance when $M$ is a moduli space of vector bundles on a curve.

Comment: Does a partial compactification of $T^*M$ such that the map becomes proper, always exist ?